# How can I set up my own VPN on my cloud server?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, network-share

What I want to do is to have a VPN that I can connect to from when travelling to get a safer and faster connection.  I have OSX - can I set it up so that I can use OSX's built in VPN service?

My cloud box is Ubuntu 12.04.

I also would like to know how to set it up so that my friends can use this VPN as well, and that we can be on the same network and share folders (and eg. Bonjour sharing in OSX) - even if being in different places, but connected on the VPN.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where in the stackoverflow universe should this Q be posted? Or is there no room in the S universe for such a Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup an IPSEC vpn using strongswan which is available on ubuntu 12.04. You will be able to use the builtin VPN client with no need to install additional software on Mac OSX.

A writeup on setup for Centos which you can adopt for Ubuntu can be found here http://www.topdog.za.net/2012/08/23/iphone-ipad-mac-osx-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-5-on-centos-rhel-6/

Comment: thanks, trying it now. but what's a CA? it's not installed with strongswan.

Comment: yet another incompatible tutorial :/

Comment: thanks though - and now i've managed to at least connect the server and client. i can ping server from client - but not client from server.  Sorry if this is all off-topic. Not sure how that is though.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this tonight!

I use Tunnelblick on my mac...with configuration files generating during this tutorial:

https://library.linode.com/networking/openvpn/debian-6-squeeze

Be sure to do the last steps about tunneling.

Worked like a charm if you follow the steps.